# What is the standard way to check a variable is initialised as a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, null, nan

I am trying to test a variable to ensure [a] it is initialised and [b] and is a number before supplying the number as an argument. I have tried to do this using two functions `noNil(i)` and `noNan(i)`. It makes sense to find if a variable is initialised before testing if it is a number. But it makes little difference which function is called first. The first alert reports `undefined` while the second alert report nothing. What is the standard way to check a variable is initialised as a number in pure javascript ?

e.g.

```
    var i;

    noNil();
    alert(i);
    noNaN(i);
    alert(i);

    function noNil(i) {
      if (i === undefined){
      let i = -1;
        return i;
      }
    }

    function noNan(i) {         
      if (isNaN(i)) {
      let i = 30;   
        return i;
      }
    }
```

**Clarification**

A bit of context might help. The variable is defined in 5 ways; 0 to 4 select colours from an array. If it is undefined none of the colours is selected.

```
    let family    = ["yellow", "red", "lime", "cyan","magenta"];
    ...
    ctx.fillStyle = family[i];
```

Comment: These functions do nothing. You declare a local variable and then return it but you don't do anything with the returned value

Comment: `var i` ... `function x(i)` ... `let i` ... just letting you know that `i` is not the only name a variable can have ...

Comment: @JaromandaX I think op wanted to change that value of variable `i`

Comment: @Konrad - I know that, perhaps there were so many `i`'s he couldn't see ...

Comment: There probably isn't a "standard" way, and it depends if you want to allow automatic type conversion (which is not clarified in the post). If you just want to test if a value is a non-NaN **primitive number** already (without type conversion) you could use `const isNumber = n=> (+n===n);`

Comment: You could probably try `ctx.fillStyle = family[i] ?? family[family.length-1;` or something. If you want to know if it's a number, use `typeof i === 'number'`, as it will be `undefined` or `object` for `null` (that last one only because of historical reasons).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `typeof i === 'number'` to determine whether the value is of the JS number type.

```js
const checkNumber = i => { if( typeof i !== 'number') throw new Error('Supplied argument is not a number!'); return i;};

function sum(a, b){
  return checkNumber(a) + checkNumber(b);
}

console.log(sum(2, 2));

var i;

console.log(sum(i, 2));
```

About your use case with selecting colors, you could avoid bothering with numbers:

```
let family    = ["yellow", "red", "lime", "cyan","magenta"];
family[i] && (ctx.fillStyle = family[i]);
```

But the main question could be why you are ending up with `i` not being a number of a proper index of your color array...

If you want to check strings the topic suddenly becomes much more complex (I don't even cover all cases here like scientific notation):

```js
var i;

function isNumber(i) {
  return typeof i === 'number';
}

function isNumerish(i) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(i));
}

function isStringNumber(i) {
  return /^-?\d*\.?\d+$/.test(i);
}

const checks = [[i, isNumber], [-.5, isNumber], ['-.5a', isNumerish], ['-.5a', isStringNumber], ['-.5', isStringNumber]];

for(const [num, fn] of checks){
  console.log(num, fn.name, fn(num));
}
```

Comment: Alexander, this not only offers a way to solve my immediate problem but covers aspects of the question I hadn't considered. Much appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var i;

if(!!i) {
   console.log("undefined or null or (falsy) ");
}
else {
   console.log("The value of i is ", i);
}
```