# Checking if a value is found in an array using user input

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, user-input

I am currently learning JavaScript Arrays and am trying to do a small program that allows a user to enter a value input. From there, once they click on the "Check" button, the JavaScript is meant to loop through the array and check if the value is found within.
If so, a success message is printed, if the value is not found the program prompts the user to try again.

My issue is I am having trouble with looping through the array to find the value. Below is all my code, and I would appreciate the help!

```js
const numbers = [58, 4, 17, 32, 24, 53, 44, 99, 70, 56, 72,
  43, 36, 51, 37, 46, 35, 25, 29, 64, 76, 21,
  82, 94, 47, 12, 19, 31, 69, 81, 20, 91, 50,
  3, 34, 79, 2, 27, 68, 52, 23, 22, 84, 18, 16,
  33, 13, 39, 77, 8
];

let value = document.getElementById("num");
let output = document.getElementById("display");

function printValue() {
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (value == i) {
      output.innerHTML = value.value;
      output.innerHTML = "Value was found in the array!"
    }
  }
  output.innerHTML = "Value is not found in array, please try again";

}

value.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("sub").click();
  }
})
```

```html
<h1>Check to see if your value is found in an array</h1>

<label for="num">Enter value:</label>
<input type="text" id="num" name="num">
<br><br>

<button id="sub" onclick="printValue()">Check</button>
<br><br>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues in your code:

1. You are comparing the element with the index where you should compare the element's value with array value.
2. You have to `return` from the function after a match found.
3. I will also suggest you to convert the value to number and use strict equality (`===`) operator for checking. I will also suggest you to use [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) instead of `innerHTML`.

Try the following way:

```html
<h1>Check to see if your value is found in an array</h1>

<label for="num">Enter value:</label>
<input type="text" id="num" name="num">
<br><br>

<button id="sub" onclick="printValue()">Check</button>
<br><br>
<div id="display"></div>

<script>
    const numbers = [58, 4, 17, 32, 24, 53, 44, 99, 70, 56, 72, 
                    43, 36, 51, 37, 46, 35, 25, 29, 64, 76, 21, 
                    82, 94, 47, 12, 19, 31, 69, 81, 20, 91, 50, 
                    3, 34, 79, 2, 27, 68, 52, 23, 22, 84, 18, 16, 
                    33, 13, 39, 77, 8];

    let inputEl = document.getElementById("num");
    let output = document.getElementById("display");
    function printValue() {
        let inputElVal = parseInt(inputEl.value); //get the value from the element
        output.textContent = inputElVal;
        for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            if (inputElVal === numbers[i]) { //check the input element's value with array value.
                output.textContent += " - Value was found in the array!";
                return; //return here
            }
        }
        output.innerHTML += "- Value is not found in array, please try again";

    }

    inputEl.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("sub").click();
        }
    });

</script>
```

Though I prefer using [`Array.prototype.includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) instead *for* loop:

> The `includes()` method determines whether an array includes a certain value among its entries, returning true or false as appropriate.

**Code Example:**

```html
<h1>Check to see if your value is found in an array</h1>

<label for="num">Enter value:</label>
<input type="text" id="num" name="num">
<br><br>

<button id="sub" onclick="printValue()">Check</button>
<br><br>
<div id="display"></div>

<script>
    const numbers = [58, 4, 17, 32, 24, 53, 44, 99, 70, 56, 72, 
                    43, 36, 51, 37, 46, 35, 25, 29, 64, 76, 21, 
                    82, 94, 47, 12, 19, 31, 69, 81, 20, 91, 50, 
                    3, 34, 79, 2, 27, 68, 52, 23, 22, 84, 18, 16, 
                    33, 13, 39, 77, 8];

    let inputEl = document.getElementById("num");
    let output = document.getElementById("display");
    function printValue() {
        let inputElVal = parseInt(inputEl.value); //get the value from the element
        if (numbers.includes(inputElVal)) {
            output.textContent = "Value was found in the array!";
        } else {
            output.textContent = "Value is not found in array, please try again";
        }
        
    }

    inputEl.addEventListener("keyup", function(event){
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            document.getElementById("sub").click();
        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: using `Number()` is a bad idea for parsing strings, since `Number(' ') === 0`

Comment: Wrap in a form and no need to even have a submit button but regardless the form is submitted on enter

Comment: You still overwrite the innerHTML here: `output.innerHTML = inputElVal; output.innerHTML = "Value was found in the array!";`

Answer (score 0):

In your code you compare the input's value to the `for` loop's index which doesn't have much sense. We should rather compare an array element.

There's a nice method to check whether an array has a value: [`Array::includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes).
But first we should convert the input's value to a number and pass it to `numbers.includes()`.
The problem here that parsing a string to a number is tricky. For example `Number(' ') === 0` or `parseInt('12asdf') === 12`.

Here's some parsing options of strings to numbers:
[What is the standard way to check a variable is initialised as a number in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76796883/what-is-the-standard-way-to-check-a-variable-is-initialised-as-a-number-in-javas/76797071#76797071)

So for checking if a string contains only digits we could use a regular expression.
That could be considered advanced, so check the further easier solutions.

So our `printValue()` could be compressed to 2 lines:

1. Put the messages into an array:

```
const messages = ["Value is not found in array, please try again", "Value was found in the array!"];
```

2. Select an print message with:

```
output.innerHTML = messages[+(/^(-?[1-9]+\d*|0)$/.test(inputEl.value) && numbers.includes(+inputEl.value))];
```

Here we

1. Test if the input contains only digits (with an optional sign and no leading zeros)
2. If successful test if the input's values converted with to a number with `+` (which is the same as `Number()`) is in the `numbers` with `Array::includes()`.
3. Convert the result boolean value to a number with `+` which will be the index of the corresponding message.

```html
<h1>Check to see if your value is found in an array</h1>

<label for="num">Enter value:</label>
<input type="text" id="num" name="num" oninput="printValue()">
<br><br>

<div id="display"></div>

<script>
    const numbers = [-1, 0, 58, 4, 17, 32, 24, 53, 44, 99, 70, 56, 72, 
                    43, 36, 51, 37, 46, 35, 25, 29, 64, 76, 21, 
                    82, 94, 47, 12, 19, 31, 69, 81, 20, 91, 50, 
                    3, 34, 79, 2, 27, 68, 52, 23, 22, 84, 18, 16, 
                    33, 13, 39, 77, 8];

    let inputEl = document.getElementById("num");
    let output = document.getElementById("display");

    function printValue() {
        const messages = ["Value is not found in array, please try again", "Value was found in the array!"];
        output.innerHTML = messages[+(/^(-?[1-9]+\d*|0)$/.test(inputEl.value) && numbers.includes(+inputEl.value))];
    }

</script>
```

But I guess for the OP's purposes comparing strings is easier to understand.
We could use [`Array::some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to compare strings rather than numbers:

```html
<h1>Check to see if your value is found in an array</h1>

<label for="num">Enter value:</label>
<input type="text" id="num" name="num" oninput="printValue()">
<br><br>

<div id="display"></div>

<script>
    const numbers = [-1, 0, 58, 4, 17, 32, 24, 53, 44, 99, 70, 56, 72, 
                    43, 36, 51, 37, 46, 35, 25, 29, 64, 76, 21, 
                    82, 94, 47, 12, 19, 31, 69, 81, 20, 91, 50, 
                    3, 34, 79, 2, 27, 68, 52, 23, 22, 84, 18, 16, 
                    33, 13, 39, 77, 8];

    let inputEl = document.getElementById("num");
    let output = document.getElementById("display");

    function printValue() {
        const messages = ["Value is not found in array, please try again", "Value was found in the array!"];
        output.innerHTML = messages[+numbers.some(num => num.toString() === inputEl.value)];
    }

</script>
```

Regarding the OP's code it could be fixed as:

```js
const numbers = [58, 4, 17, 32, 24, 53, 44, 99, 70, 56, 72,
  43, 36, 51, 37, 46, 35, 25, 29, 64, 76, 21,
  82, 94, 47, 12, 19, 31, 69, 81, 20, 91, 50,
  3, 34, 79, 2, 27, 68, 52, 23, 22, 84, 18, 16,
  33, 13, 39, 77, 8
];

let value = document.getElementById("num");
let output = document.getElementById("display");

function printValue() {
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (value.value === numbers[i].toString()) {
      output.innerHTML = "Value was found in the array!"
      // here you should return to not allow to print the invalid messages
      return;
    }
  }
  output.innerHTML = "Value is not found in array, please try again";

}

value.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode === 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById("sub").click();
  }
})
```

```html
<h1>Check to see if your value is found in an array</h1>

<label for="num">Enter value:</label>
<input type="text" id="num" name="num"><button id="sub" onclick="printValue()">Check</button>
<br><br>
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: Considering that OP is a self confessed "beginner" it seems to me that your solution might be a little over-engineered. The regular expression `/^(-?[1-9]+\d*|0)$/` will, for example, disallow entries like "04", " 4", "4." or "4 ". I can well imagine that OP would be content with just checking `numbers.includes(+inputEl.value)`.

Comment: @CarstenMassmann that was the point to disallow fuzzy matching. I've provided easier solutions after this one though

Comment: @CarstenMassmann `+' ' === 0` unfortunately

Comment: That is true. But maybe OP even _wants_ that as a positive case? And maybe OP also wants "4.0" or " 4 " to be a positive case? We don't really know. Maybe using `<input type="number">` instead of `type="text"` might be helpful here?

Answer (score 0):

Add `return`

```
function printValue() {
  for (let i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    if (value == i) {
      output.innerHTML = value.value;
      output.innerHTML = "Value was found in the array!"
      return
    }
  }
  output.innerHTML = "Value is not found in array, please try again";

}
```

Comment: The `return` is helpful here, yes, but your comparison is still off. It should at least be something like `value.value == numbers[i]` (if we want to allow "fuzzy matches"). And `output.innerHTML = value.value;` is also completely superfluous here